# How to validate the whole form with parsley.js

Tags: parsley.js

I am trying to figure out the best way to validate a form as a whole. The individual fields all have field level validation, they are numbers and ranges of numbers i.e 2-5. But then there can be an interdependence between the numbers:

- Are they increasing,
- Are there any gaps between the numbers
- Do they cover an overall range.

> Example: Overall range 1-10
>
> - Field 1: 1
> - Field 2: 2-4
> - Field 3: 5
> - Field 4: 6-9
> - Field 5: 10

This would be valid, but if field 2 was 2-3, it would be invalid as 4 would be missing, likewise if the values of field 3 and field 4 were switch it would also be invalid.

I can do some of this with field level validation, but for clarities sake i would like to have a routine which evaluated the set of fields as a whole.

I looked in the manual, did not see anything obvious, what would be the best way to do this? A hidden field with a custom validator? Can i somehow specify that a specific field's validation should be last, not sure it matters. Is there an event that will work, I found the validated event, but that happens after validation either passes or fails not really part of the validation process.

The above is just an example, the final product will have many more fields and more interdependence.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [one way to do it in the examples](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html)

Comment: Does the form:submit event fire when validation is invoked via the validate method?